# Como faço para aplicar uma condição em uma linha que pule a próxima? (iniciante em python)

Tags: python, string

Sou bem iniciante em python e estou fazendo uma calculadora simples, mas tenho uma dúvida que não acho em nenhum lugar. Quero fazer uma condição para, se a operação escolhida for `*/` (o que usei para simbolizar raiz quadrada), ele ignore a próxima pergunta. exemplificando:

```
n1 = int(input('Digite o número 1: '))
op = input('Digite a operação: ')
n2 = int(input('Digite o número 2: '))
```

eu quero que, se eu digitar `*/` (respondendo a op) ele pule a próxima ordem, que seria `Digite o número 2:` e vá direto pro cálculo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples, Eric. No seu caso é só encapsular o `n2` em um `if` e fazer o teste da operação. Se o valor **não for** `*/`, que simboliza sua raiz quadrada, então a linha é executada, senão ela vai ser pulada:

```
n1 = int(input('Digite o número 1: '))
op = input('Digite a operação: ')
if op != '*/':
    n2 = int(input('Digite o número 2: '))
```

Como você é iniciante talvez caiba aqui uma breve explicação: o `!=` usado no teste do `if` simboliza **diferente de** em Python

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Funcionou muito bem!!!